# Email cannot be sent in Python.[Errno 61] Connection refused error happens

Tags: python, django

Email cannot be sent in Python.I want to send an email by using Gmail.
I wrote codes in views.py like

```
    def mail(mail_adress, docx):

            msg = MIMEMultipart()
            msg["Subject"] = "TEST"
            msg["From"] = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
            msg["To"] = email

            message = "TEST"
            body = MIMEText(message)
            msg.attach(body)

            mime = {'type': 'text', 'subtype': 'docx'}
            attach_file = {'name': 'test.docx', 'path': '/Users/test.docx'}

            attachment = MIMEBase(mime['type'], mime['subtype'])
            file = open(attach_file['path'], 'rb')
            attachment.set_payload(file.read())
            file.close()
            encoders.encode_base64(attachment)
            msg.attach(attachment)
            attachment.add_header("Content-Disposition", "attachment", filename=attach_file['name'])

            return msg

    def send(from_addr, to_addrs, msg):
        smtp = smtplib.SMTP()
        smtp.connect()

        from_addr = 'xxxx@gmail.com'
        from_addr_name = "test"
        to_addr= "yyyyy@gmail.com"
        subject = u"test"
        message = "test"
        body = MIMEText(message)
        mime = {'type': 'text', 'subtype': 'docx'}
        attach_file = {'name': 'test.docx', 'path': '/Users/test.docx'}

        msg = mail(from_addr, from_addr_name, to_addr, subject, body, mime, attach_file)
        smtp.sendmail(from_addr, to_addrs, msg)
        smtp.close()

    send()
```

in settings.py

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'xxxx@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'xxxxxxxxx'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

When I run the codes,
[Errno 61] Connection refused error happens.Traceback says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xxxx/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/xxxx/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 128, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/xxxx/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/xxxx/Downloads/legal_doc_mail/common/views.py", line 400, in make_document
    send()
  File "/Users/xxxx/Downloads/legal_doc_mail/common/views.py", line 454, in send
    smtp.connect()
  File "/Users/xxxx/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 336, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/Users/xxxx/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 307, in _get_socket
    self.source_address)
  File "/Users/xxxx/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 724, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/Users/xxxx/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 713, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

I really cannot understand why such an error happens.What is wrong in my codes?How should I fix this?

Comment: I had this same issue on my G Suite business account and had to lower the security settings.

Comment: @joshlsullivan I lower the security settings, but same thing happens...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Settings.py

   ```
   EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
   EMAIL_PORT = 587
   EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'xxxx@gmail.com'
   EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'xxxxxxxxx'
   EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
   EMAIL_USE_SSL = False
   ```
2. Go to your Google Account settings, find Security -> Account permissions -> Access for less secure apps, enable let less secure apps sign in option.
   https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255

[Errorno 61] is due to connection refused by server. See if this could help.

Comment: thank you for your answer.Traceback shows address is ('localhost', 25).Localhost is ok?Port number is wrong ,isn't it?

Comment: I don't think there's any issue with the port number. The request is going to the server but the connection is denied by it. Try & see if the above steps resolve the issue. Also, the traceback you have added here doesn't show the address is the port number is wrong.